# Pygame bouncing ball

Tags: python, pygame

So I am very new to pygame and I am trying to create a few different slides, like 6 or so of  a ball bouncing.  Each one of them will have the ball at a different height off the ground and what not.  I have been trying to figure out how to start this.  I don't really know how to combine a bunch of different slides to create a gif type image that is basically a slideshow of the six different images I will be creating if that makes any sense.  I havent started it yet so I don't have any code.  I know how to create the images obviously but I don't know how to combine them all, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your trying to make an animation sort of thing then just simply load the 6 pictures, put them into a list and count through the list blitting as you go.

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pic1 = pygame.image.load("pic1.png")
pic2 = pygame.image.load("pic2.png")
pic3 = pygame.image.load("pic3.png")
pic4 = pygame.image.load("pic4.png")
pic5 = pygame.image.load("pic5.png")
pic6 = pygame.image.load("pic6.png")

counter = 0
pics = [pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, pic5, pic6]
x = 100
y = [10, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250]

while(1): ## infinite loop 

    screen.blit(pics[counter], (x, y[counter])) ## this will change position for the different heights
    counter += 1

    if counter >= 5:
        counter = 0
```

This is a very basic example, change the pic names to your pics and your good to go!
Hope this helped.